# Synonyms for embarrassing oneself

Tags: synonyms

What's a word to describe an action that is considered wrong and sometimes immoral, taken by a person whom you wouldn't expect that from. For example, when a politician is caught receiving illegal money, we can say that he embarrassed himself with that. But would there be another expression besides embarrassing oneself in this case? A word or expression that conveyed a stronger connotation?

Comment: ... *embarrassed himself **with** that.*

Comment: discredited himself

Comment: "Lost credibility", "burned trust", "let people to question his judgement", "questionable judgement",  "tarnished image", "tarnished reputation" , "tarnished their credibility", "ruined reputation", "confidence rending", "confidence"/with others words above

Comment: "diminished trust", "diminished reputation", "questionable reputation", "beneath their dignity" "damaged dignity"

Comment: "tainted reputation", "tainted image"

Comment: You could say that they *betrayed their character* or that their actions are a *disappointment*.

Comment: "Got caught with his hand in the cookie jar"

Answer (score 2):

I hear **unbecoming** used a lot in this way.

"His behavior was unbecoming the office of the presidency."